# PL/SQL Query to check row's length

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracleforms

I'm having some trouble on solving this.

I have to check on the table, if there's any row that exceed the length of 34 characters (for this, I'm using this first part of the query using Lenght command), if found, return the error with the variable 'END_CNPJ$' (that's being populated by the second part of the query 'ENDERECO') so the user can see which row has more than 34 characters. Is this code correct (probably not)? If it isn't, how can I fix it?

```
SELECT 
  LENGTH(CONCAT (CONCAT (CONCAT(CONCAT (CONCAT (CONCAT (CONCAT (
                       '', T.TTIPO_LOGR), 
                         ''), T.TENDERE),
                           ''), T.NNRO_ENDER),
                             ''),T.TCOMPL_ENDER) ), 
  T.TTIPO_LOGR || ' ' || T.TENDERE || ', ' || T.NNRO_ENDER || ' ' || T.TCOMPL_ENDER || ' - ' || TMUNICI || ' CNPJ: ' || T.NCGC AS ENDERECO
   INTO CHARACTER_COUNT$, END_CNPJ$
                                FROM TBENDER T 
                                 WHERE T.CEMPRES = :ENDER_BLK.CEMPRES;
                                 
  IF CHARACTER_COUNT$ > 34 THEN
    MSG_ALERT_COSMO(' You exceeded 34 character for this address: ' || END_CNPJ$ );
    RAISE FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE;
  END IF;
```

I hope I'm not violating any rule, just got here yesterday :D

TIA

Comment: Tip: Use `||` for concatenation. Like `str1 || str2 || str3`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @jarlh ! I'll do it on the definitive code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's actually Oracle **Forms**, is it not? `raise form_trigger_failure` and `:ender_blk` smell so.

In that case, the only *drawback* might be possibility of no rows in that table for block item value (which will raise `no_data_found`) or two or more rows for it (which will then raise too_many_rows).

Other than that, this *should* be OK.

Though, it is kind of unclear why you nicely concatenated values (using the double pipe `||` operator) for `END_CNPJ$` and nested that many `concat` functions for `CHARACTER_COUNT$`.

Also, you didn't post the whole trigger code (missing declarations, `begin-end` keywords, perhaps something else).

But, as I said, in general - that's OK.

Comment: Yes, it is Oracle Forms! Sorry I didn't posted the entire code, it is very extensive, but the only part I'm afraid it's wrong, it's this one I quoted. This is not the definitive Code, I'll use the double pipe on the definitive one, thanks for the tip!